# UITextView linkTextAttributes set accessibility value

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextview, accessibility, nsattributedstring

I created a text view that has one line of text and part of the text is a link. I use `linkTextAttributes` to create that clickable link text, but I cannot get accessibility to work.

I am able to click on the link, but in "Accessibility Inspector", when I hover over the text view, it sees it as one accessibility element and won't be able to detect the clickable text.

However, in Accessibility Inspector, under Hierarchy section, I'm able to see the Link, but I just can't set it's accessibility label and value.

---

The entire text view is one accessibility element

[image: The entire text view is one accessibility element]

However, it shows up under Hierarchy

[image: However, it shows up under Hierarchy]

I want to be able to modify the accessibility value in this MORE clickable text. But I am not able to get the accessibility of MORE text in code at all.

[image]

Comment: Did you implement the textview's delegate shouldInteractWithUrl? When you click on that More text this method should get called.

Comment: @Cathy Oun i have the same issue. we're you able to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we can actually make it possible to voice over the link text seperately as it is still a string which do not have "isAccessibilityElement". However, this can be achieved If we create a CustomTextView with a label and a button.